# Remove odd numbers in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am trying to come up with another way to remove all of the odd numbers from an array. A friend was able to come up with this solution and I understand what it does, but I am failing to find another solution to it. Do you have any ideas for another solution to do this?

JavaScript

```
let myArray = [1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8];
let it = myArray.length;

for(let i=0; i<it; i++) {
  for(let j=0; j<myArray.length; j++ )
    if(myArray[j]%2 === 1){
      myArray.splice(j,1)
      break;
    }
  };

  console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: *"another solution"* - There are lots of possible solutions, but I doubt you can find anything simpler than `.filter()`. By the way, the solution shown may *work*, but it doesn't make much sense: the outer loop will run through to the *original* array length even after items are removed, and the inner loop always restarts with the first element so you're reprocessing elements for no reason. (And `it` is a terrible variable name.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question asks how to "remove odds", not how to "keep evens" – the result is the same in this case, but the way you derive the answer could vary. There's not always a perfect opposite function that plugs directly into `Array.prototype.filter`, so all answers here will be in the context of removing elements where we only a way to detect odd values – not keeping elements that are even. I'll detail a wide variety of ways to solve your problem, but first let's review your code

**your friend's answer**

I added a `console.log` on your inner loop so you can see each element you're checking. It's easy to see that this solution is doing more work than it has to - there's no need to create more than *1* loop to iterate thru your array of numbers.

```js
let myArray = [1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8]
let it = myArray.length

for(let i = 0; i < it; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++ ) {
    console.log('checking:', myArray[j])
    if(myArray[j] % 2 === 1) {
      myArray.splice(j,1)
      break
    }
  }
}

console.log(myArray)
```

Also important, you need to be very mindful when changing the length of an array as you're iterating thru it. For example, if you call `arr.splice(i,1)`, what effect does that have on your loop?

- all elements to the right of "i" will shift left 1 place
- the length of the array decreases by 1

So how should your loop accommodate for that?

- if all elements shift left after a splice, that means we need to re-check the same `i` once more because it now points to a new value
- if the length decreases by 1, we need to change the loop exit condition to stop 1 iteration sooner

The `mutRejectOdds` answer below addresses these issues

---

**recursive function**

highly readable and straightforward but not stack-safe

```js
const isOdd = x => x & 1 === 1

const removeOdds = ([x,...xs]) => {
  if (x === undefined)
    return []
  else if (isOdd(x))
    return removeOdds(xs)
  else
    return [x, ...removeOdds(xs)]
}

let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
console.log(removeOdds(data)) // [2,4,6,8]
console.log(data)             // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

---

**linear iterative with accumulator**

stack-safe and highly practical

```js
const isOdd = x => x & 1 === 1

const removeOdds = xs => {
  let acc = []
  for (let x of xs)
    if (!isOdd(x))
      acc.push(x)
  return acc
}

let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
console.log(removeOdds(data)) // [2,4,6,8]
console.log(data)             // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

---

**continuation passing style**

brain-twisting but super fun recursive solution that could be put on a trampoline to make stack-safe

```js
const isOdd = x => x & 1 === 1

const identity = x => x

const removeOdds = xs => {
  const aux = ([x,...xs], k) => {
    if (x === undefined)
      return k([])
    else if (isOdd(x))
      return aux(xs, k)
    else
      return aux(xs, acc => k([x, ...acc]))
  }
  return aux(xs, identity)
}

let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
console.log(removeOdds(data)) // [2,4,6,8]
console.log(data)             // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

---

**higher-order function**

similar to the recursive function, but instead accepts another argument which is a function of elements to skip - could be written in linear iterative style or continuation passing style too

```js
const isOdd = x => x & 1 === 1

const reject = (f, [x,...xs]) => {
  if (x === undefined)
    return []
  else if (f(x))
    return reject(f, xs)
  else
    return [x, ...reject(f, xs)]
}

let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
console.log(reject(isOdd, data)) // [2,4,6,8]
console.log(data)                // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

---

**function composition with Array.prototype.filter**

uses the highly practical built-in `Array.prototype.filter` but returns the opposite result using function composition with `not`

```js
const isOdd = x => x & 1 === 1

const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x))

const not = x => !x

const reject = (f, xs) =>
  xs.filter(comp(not)(f))

let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
console.log(reject(isOdd, data)) // [2,4,6,8]
console.log(data)                // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

---

**linear iterative with in-place mutation**

all methods I implemented above do *not* mutate the original `data` - in some cases, if you had a particularly large array and you did not want to create a *copy* with odd values removed, you might wish to perform an in-place modification of `data`

this answer addresses the issues in your original code

```js
const isOdd = x => x & 1 === 1

const mutRejectOdds = xs => {
  for (let i = 0, len = xs.length; i < len; i++)
    if (isOdd(xs[i]))
      (xs.splice(i,1), i--, len--)
}

let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
console.log(mutRejectOdds(data)) // undefined
console.log(data)                // [2,4,6,8]
```

Answer (score 8):

```js
let myArray = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8];

myArray = myArray.filter(e => e % 2 === 0)

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need support as far back as IE9 you can use the Array.prototype.filter method.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var output = arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item % 2 === 0;
});
```

Output will be a new array of the filtered values (Only even).